# Running cucumber with activator

Tags: scala, sbt, cucumber, typesafe-activator

I am new to cucumber and using it with sbt and Scala. I want to run the same with Lightbend activator. Is there any plugin available to run cucumber specifications through activator as well? e.g. To run the tests, I should run a command like: 
`activator cucumber` instead of 
`sbt cucumber`. 
Please help. Thanks in advance!